# How to create a road on a sphere in Unity 5?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a low poly sphere(planet) in Blender and imported it into unity. I have set up the trees and everything else but I am unable to create a road. I have been googling for a while but haven't found anything.

[image: game play[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzQOH.png)

I need to create a road and then place coins on the road. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not make the road in blender too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a 3D model of a road and place it on the sphere.